# How to avoid nested h:form (s)?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

Due to some presentation needs I have got stuck with a `h:form` tag inside a parent `h:form`. How should I make this work without disturbing the look of the page ?

```
    <h:form>
        ....
        ....

        <h:outputText value="Your city not listed? Add here..">
        <p:dialog>
             <h:form>   
                <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#gpController.create()}" />
             </h:form>                 
        </p:dialog>

        ....
        ....
    </h:form>
```

Comment: What are those 'some presentation needs'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the dialog outside the form. It really doesn't matter to the UI where the dialog component is located in the view.

```html
<h:form>
   ...
   <h:outputText value="Your city not listed? Add here..">
   ...
</h:form>
<p:dialog>
     <h:form>   
        <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{gpController.create()}" />
     </h:form>                 
</p:dialog>
```